# How to remove all non word characters except ä,ö and ü from a text using RegExp

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a file and I want to remove all non-word characters from it, with the exception of `ä`, `ö` and `ü`, which are mutated vowels in the German language. Is there a way to do `word.gsub!(/\W/, '')` and put exceptions in it?

Example:

```
text = "übung bzw. äffchen"
text.gsub!(/\W/, '').
```

Now it would return `"bungbzwffchen"`. It deletes the non word characters, but also removes the mutated vowels `ü` and `ä`, which I want to keep.

Comment: Could you please provide an example to check against? Like "I expect `regex("abc")` to return `b`". Thank you.

Comment: text = "übung bzw. äffchen" text.gsub!(/\W/, ''). Now it would return "bungbzwffchen". It deletes the non word characters, but also removes the mutated vowels ü and ä, which I want to keep

Comment: @AshmaN3D Edit your question instead of adding comments so people interested in answering the question don't have to dig through the comment section

Comment: Don't forget  ẞ / ß

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to define a list of exclusions by using some kind of negative-lookback thing, but the simplest I think would be to just use `\w` instead of `\W` and negate the whole group:

```
word.gsub!(/[^\wÄäÖöÜü]/, '')
```

You could also use `word.gsub(/[^\p{Letter}]/, '')`, that should get rid of any characters that are not listed as "Letter" in unicode.

You mention German vowels in your question, I think it's worth noting here that the German alphabet also includes the long-s : ẞ / ß

Update:

To answer your original question, to define a list of exclusions, you use the "negative look-behind" `(?<!pat)`:

```
word.gsub(/\W(?<![ÄäÖöÅåẞß])/, '')
```

Comment: Good answer. Might be worth clarifying that `\W` is simply `[^\w]` on its own.

Comment: The `\p{...}` documentation can be found [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Character+Properties).

Comment: So \W and [^\w] are the same? But why does it work with [^\w] and not with \W?

Comment: The `^` just works in character classes `[^...]` but you can put `\w` inside a character class to include all word characters. `[a-zäöü]` would work if you just want lower case.

Comment: `\W` also just defines a character class and is a shorthand for something like `[ ,.-()=!"#]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `&&` operator within a character class:

```
text = "übung bzw. äffchen  ÄÖÜ"

text.gsub(/[\W&&[^äÄöÖüÜ]]/, '')
  #=> "übungbzwäffchenÄÖÜ"
```

The regular expression reads, "match a character in the set of characters formed by intersecting the set of all non-word characters with the set of all characters other than those in the string `"äÄöÖüÜ"`. See [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html) (search for "&& operator").